# Azure Data lake with SSIS Data Filtering

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-lake, msbi

I am using Data lake as a source in SSIS but i want to fetch or filter some specific rows in SSIS. Could you please suggest how can we filter Azure data lake data in SSIS.

Comment: To whom my be considered, they do not want fetch data to Ssis and then execute filter on data. They want to reduce number of rows that they are fetching. Am i understanding right?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `conditional Split` or `Derived Column` after the `Data Lake Store Source` in the `Data Flow`

I'm not sure how you want to filter some specific rows. I assume like filter the row which is having first two characters as **AB** 
`(DT_STR,5000,1252)SUBSTRING([Column 0],1,2) != "AB"`

[image]

Comment: In this case Data lake will fetch all records but i required some specific records from Source.

Comment: @RahulJain put your specific records condition in the `Condition` Column. In my above example. I've filtered the records which starting with **AB** as `(DT_STR,5000,1252)SUBSTRING([Column 0],1,2) != "AB"`. You can define your condition like this

Comment: @RahulJain Did my above answer helpful to you? Please upvote/accept the answer in such case